# Compare column of csv in java

Tags: sorting, csv

I'm reading a csv file with my 'CsvReader' like this:

```
public class CsvReader {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Map<String,Employee> empl = new HashMap <String,Employee>();
        String csvFile= "C:/Users/rapurohi/Desktop/employee.csv";
        BufferedReader br=null;
        String line= "";
        String csvSplitBy=",";

        try{                
            br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line =br.readLine())!=null){

                String [] employee=line.split(csvSplitBy);
                Employee e=new Employee(employee[0], employee[1], employee[2]);
                empl.put((employee[0]),e);
                System.out.println("Employee[id="+employee[0]+"name="+employee[1]+"salary="+employee[2]+"]" );
            }               
       }catch (FileNotFoundException|IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
       }

        }finally{
            if(br!=null){
                try{
                    br.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

The csv i'm using looks like this:

```
empid,name,salary
"456","John","4000"
"457","James","5000"
"458","Jack","3000"
"459","Jenny","6000"
```

The dataVO for employee looks like

package com.cg.dto;

public class Employee {

String empId;

String empName;

String empSalary;

public String getEmpId() {

return empId;

}

public void setEmpId(String empId) {

this.empId = empId;

}

public String getEmpName() {

return empName;

}

public void setEmpName(String empName) {

this.empName = empName;

}

public String getEmpSalary() {

return empSalary;

}

public void setEmpSalary(String empSalary) {

this.empSalary = empSalary;

}

public Employee(String empId, String empName, String empSalary) {

super();

this.empId = empId;

this.empName = empName;

this.empSalary = empSalary;

}

I need to find the maximum salary and write the entry in a Csv file as output.

Comment: What is happening that you don't expect?

Comment: i am stuck at this. how should i go ahead that it allows me to take the salary column and give out the max salary in a seperate csv.

Comment: @Choirbean collections and iterator don't work because of employee object in Hashmap.

Comment: `empl.values()` should return a `Collection<Employee>`.

Comment: actually collections.max(empl.values()) is not applicable for type employee

Comment: You didn't show us the code for Employee, but does it extend comparable? Max employs the "natural ordering" of items.  Items that cannot be sorted in order have no natural ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only need help with finding the maximum salary, here's a quick example:

```
int maxSal = 0;
Employee highestPayedEmployee = null;
for (Employee employee : empl.values()) {
    if(employee.getSalary() > maxSal){
        maxSal = employee.getSalary();
        highestPayedEmployee = employee;
    }
}
```

This assumes that your Employee class has a getSalary() method that returns the salary as a number.

If needed you can convert a string to a number with:

```
Integer.parseInt(salaryString);
```

Comment: i read the salary from a csv, so reads as a string. can you suggest and answer for that

Comment: If you look really carefully at the last thing in this answer you should find a hint on how to "convert an string to a number". If you really need more help than this I suggest you post your Employee class as well in your question so we can tell what should change there to make things work.

Comment: as requested i have put the employee file. I want to find the maximum salary of the employee from the three records and write to a new CSV file.

Comment: the quickfix on my example code is to use `maxSal = Integer.parseInt(employee.getSalary());` instead. But you're actually better of parsing the salary to an `int` inside the `Employee` class. Make it store an int and do the `Integer.parseInt(...)` inside the constructor / setter instead.